# How to change request parameters before passing request to nginx reverse proxy server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I am using Nginx to proxy request to some backend server.
For this, i am using proxy_pass module to redirect.
Config file:
location = /hello {
proxy_pass: abc.com
}

I want to execute the following workflow.
Request to nginx server --> change request parameters --> pass the request to abc.com --> change the response parameters --> send response back to client.

Is this possible with nginx ? Any help/pointers to this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change/set new parameters with this

```
location /hello {
  proxy_pass: abc.com 
  if ($args ~* paramToChange=(.+)) {
    set $args newParamName=$1;
  }
  set $args otherParam=value;
}
```

Update:

There is not a way in nginx out of the box to make a request to get params dynamically then apply them to another request before sending the client response.

You can do this by adding a module to nginx called [lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#readme).

This module can be recompiled into nginx by downloading it and adding it in the .configure options during installation. Also I like the [openresty](https://openresty.org/) bundle that comes with it and other useful modules already available, like echo.

Once you have the lua module this server code will work:

```
server {
    listen 8083;

    location /proxy/one {
        proxy_set_header testheader test1;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }

    location /proxy/two {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
    }

    location / {
        default_type text/html; 

        content_by_lua '
            local first = ngx.location.capture("/proxy/one",
               { args = { test = "test" } }
            )

            local testArg = first.body

            local second = ngx.location.capture("/proxy/two",
               { args = { test = testArg } }
            )

            ngx.print(second.body)
        ';

    }
}
```

I tested this configuration with a couple of node js servers like this:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var http = require('http');

startServerOne();
startServerTwo();

function startServerOne() {
  var app = koa();


  app.use(function *(next){
    console.log('\n------ Server One ------');
    console.log('this.request.headers.testheader: ' + JSON.stringify(this.request.headers.testheader));
    console.log('this.request.query: ' + JSON.stringify(this.request.query));

    if (this.request.query.test == 'test') {
      this.body = 'First query worked!';
    }else{
      this.body = 'this.request.query: ' + JSON.stringify(this.request.query);
    }  
  });

  http.createServer(app.callback()).listen(8081);

  console.log('Server 1 - 8081');
}

function startServerTwo(){
  var app = koa();
  app.use(function *(next){

    console.log('\n------ Server Two ------');
    console.log('this.request.query: ' + JSON.stringify(this.request.query));

    if (this.request.query.test == 'First query worked!') {
      this.body = 'It Worked!';
    }else{
      this.body = 'this.request.query: ' + JSON.stringify(this.request.query);
    }
  });

  http.createServer(app.callback()).listen(8082);

  console.log('Server 2 - 8082');
}
```

This was the output from the node console logs:

```
Server 1 - 8081
Server 2 - 8082

------ Server One ------
this.request.headers.testheader: "test1"
this.request.query: {"test":"test"}

------ Server Two ------
this.request.query: {"test":"First query worked!"}
```

Here's what happens:

1. Nginx sends server one a request query with the test parameter set.
2. Node server 1 sees the test parameter and responds with 'First query worked!'.
3. Nginx updates the query parameters with the body from the server one response.
   Nginx sends server two a request with the new query parameters.
4. Node server 2 sees that the 'test' query parameter equals 'First query worked!' and responds to the request with response body 'It Worked!'.

And the curl response  or visiting localhost:8083 in a browser shows 'It worked':

```
curl -i 'http://localhost:8083'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty/1.9.3.2
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 16:57:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

It Worked!
```

Comment: The new parameters are dynamic in nature. I need to call some kind of network call or service call to fill that parameter. Also i want to set some parameters before making call to proxy pass.

Comment: I added an update above. The first server call could be replaced with the network or service call that you need. The response from the first server is used to set parameters before a call to a second server.